# html5 cube slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to know how to make the [faces of a 3D slideshow](http://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-3d-cube-slideshow/) interactive i.e adding links  on it.If  creating multiple faces or walls is the way to go does that mean  I put a layer over each wall and is so  how would I do that?
In the end each wall should be able to be treated individually but all still in this cube form.
This is the slideshow I'm talking about
http://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-3d-cube-slideshow/

Thanks alot for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, they aren't really html objects. The "walls" are created using the canvas tag - which basically just means javascript. If you want to make it more interactive, I'd recommend that you look into CSS animation instead. You could probably achieve the same results using CSS. Search google for CSS animated cube or something like that.

Comment: Ho hum,seems here is something that pretty much adds up to what I want http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/